# Sell products in pairs ( only 2, 4, 6 pieces so on)

Tags: commerce

We need to sell certain SKUs in pairs, not sure how to approach it in Commerce 2. So that shall be per SKU setting.

There is say https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_limits but it only sets min and max items value.

Stock nanagement is not needed though. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry for being a smartass, but why don't you simply add something like "Whatever product (pack of 2)" into your product title?

Comment: Not a bad idea actually! Otherwise just a stock flexibility and not turning off customers with perceived high price. But also in EU you can buy one, but in US you can only buy a pair due delivery costs. Something like that.